# How to calculate a value in Blazor?

Tags: c#, asp.net, blazor

I'm working on a Blazor Server app and I have a class (`User`) that has a `Feedback` attribute. On button click I want to give a rating to my model class and calculate the feedback, but it doesn't seem to work. Also, the default value for user.Feedback is 5, so, for example if I add 4, it should be 4.5. Here's what I've done. Am I doing something wrong?

```cs
<form>
    <div class="row">
        <div class=" col-md-8">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Rate user:</label>
                <input type="number" id="rating" @bind-value="@rating" placeholder="rating">
            </div>
            <div class="row  my-3 px-3">
                <button class="btn btn-white ml-2" @onclick="@GiveFeedback">Give feedback</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public string UserId { get; set; }

    User user = new User();
    public int rating { get; set; }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        user = await Task.Run(() => userService.GetUserAsync(Convert.ToInt32(UserId)));
    }

    protected void GiveFeedback()
    {
        user.NumberOfFeedbacks++;
        user.Feedback=(user.Feedback+rating)/user.NumberOfFeedbacks;
    }
```

Comment: `doesn't seem to work` - in which way does it not seem to work? On a side note, this is not how you [calculate a new average](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3998780/11683) based on the old average and one new data point.

Comment: @GSerg the feedback doesn't modify

Comment: @IoanaIgnat, they are not feedback on this UI. What do you expect?

Answer (score 1):

I think it is not a Blazor specific issue. You might have a type problem and some calculation issue as well...

1. What is the type of `user.Feedback` property? Is it `int` or `double` in order to store partial (floating) number you need to use `double` or `decimal` types
2. Average calculation also seems wrong use this line: `user.Feedback=((user.Feedback * user.NumberOfFeedbacks) + rating) / user.NumberOfFeedbacks;`